# Probability of a time-dependent set of states in Markov chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process

Consider a Markov matrix $P$ defining $m$ states. For each time $n$, define a set of states $S_n$ that contains a predefined subset of the states $\left\{ {1,...,m} \right\}$.

For time $n=k$, I would like to calculate the probability that at time $n=1$ the state was one of the states in $S_1$, AND at time $n=2$ the state was one of the states in $S_2$ and so on, such that at time $n=k$ the state was one of the states in $S_k$. Is there any simple formula for calculating this probability?

As an example, consider a Markov chain with $5$ states $\left\{ {1,2,3,4,5} \right\}$, with ${S_1} = \left\{ {1,2,3} \right\},{S_2} = \left\{ {2,3} \right\},{S_3} = \left\{ {2,3,4,5} \right\}$. The question in this case is: What is the probability that at time $n=1$ the state is either $1$,$2$ or $3$, AND at time $n=2$ the state is either $2$ or $3$, AND at time $n=3$ the state is either $2,3,4$ or $5$?

Edit:

As a concrete example, consider the balls-and-bins model, where there are $m$ balls and $N$ bins, each ball is assigned independently at random to one of the bins. The states correspond to the number of non-empty bins. I would like to find the probability that the $n^{\rm th}$ ball is assigned such that at least $f(n)$ bins are already non-empty. It can be assumed that $f(n)$ is a monotonically increasing function of $n$.

Comment: Let $X_n$ be the Markov state at time $n$. An interesting aspect of this problem is that $Pr[X_{n+1}=i|X_n \in S_n]$ is _not_ the same as $Pr[X_{n+1}=i|X_n \in S_n, X_{n-1}=S_{n-1}, \ldots, X_1\in S_1]$ (so history matters, unless $S_n$ is a set with just one element).

Comment: There are ways to solve it, but, what is the context of this problem?  Why do you want to solve it?

Comment: A general hint would be to define $A_n$ as the event $\{X_1 \in S_1, X_2 \in S_2, \ldots, X_n \in S_n\}$ and then compute $Pr[X_{n+1}=j|A_n]$ recursively in terms of $Pr[X_n=j|A_{n-1}]$ via the law of total probability.

Comment: @Michael: Yes, the problem is with $|S_n|$ being in general larger than $1$. I added the context of this problem as a balls-and-bins model.

Comment: So, is this a homework problem? For your bin problem, if you assume balls are sequentially assigned and let $X_k$ be the number of non-empty bins at the end of assignment $k$ (so that $X_1=1$), it is not clear if you want to compute $Pr[X_n\geq f(n)]$ or $Pr[X_n\geq f(n), X_{n-1}\geq f(n-1), \ldots, X_1\geq f(1)]$.

Comment: For the general problem, where you able to find a relationship between $Pr[X_{n+1}=j|A_n]$ and $Pr[X_n=i|A_{n-1}]$ by conditioning on $X_n=i$ for all appropriate $i$ and using the law of total probability?

Comment: @Michael: It is not a HW problem. I am aware that there are ways to compute the desired probability, e.g. by plotting the set of possible states as a function of time (Trellis) and taking into consideration relevant paths. I am interested in the question whether it is a known problem for which simpler methods are known (maybe by raising a modified version of the Markov matrix to a power?).

Comment: The recursive method I describe above for computing $Pr[X_n=j|A_{n-1}]$ (and $Pr[A_n]$) has about the same complexity as multiplying a matrix by a vector $n$ times.  Of course, $Pr[A_n]$ typically converges to 0 as $n\rightarrow\infty$.  It is almost the same as setting some of the transition probabilities to 0, but there is a "normalizing factor."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $A_k = \{X_k \in S_k, X_{k-1} \in S_{k-1}, \ldots, X_1 \in S_1\}$. Assume that $Pr[X_1=j]$ is known for all $j \in S_1$.

For $k>1$, note that $Pr[A_k|A_{k-1}] = \frac{Pr[A_k, A_{k-1}]}{Pr[A_{k-1}]} = \frac{Pr[A_k]}{Pr[A_{k-1}]}$.

For $k>1$ define:

\begin{align} 
q[k] &= Pr[A_k|A_{k-1}]\\
r_j[k] &= Pr[X_k=j|A_{k-1}] \: \: \forall j \in S_k
\end{align}
Define $q[0]=1$, $r_j[1] = Pr[X_1=j]$.  Define $Pr[A_0]=1$.
Iterate on the following for $k\in\{1, 2, 3, \ldots\}$:

On iteration $k$:

Assume the following is known: 
$q[k-1]$, $Pr[A_{k-1}]$, and $r_j[k]$ for $j \in S_{k}$ (these are indeed known for $k=1$).

Then do the following steps:

1) Compute $q[k]$ in terms of the knowns.

2) For each $j \in S_{k+1}$, compute $r_j[k+1]$ in terms of the knowns.

3) $Pr[A_k]=q[k]Pr[A_{k-1}]$.

---

Each iteration has roughly the same complexity. On each iteration, the complexity of step 2 is about the same as the complexity of multiplying a matrix by a vector.

---

Another method would be to augment the state space by adding a "state 0" that is a "trapping state" from which, if entered, you can never leave.  Then appropriately adjust the transition probabilities.